# Auto sending notifications through one app to the other app (like a delivery boy app)

Tags: android

Sir, we are developing an app like delivery app I want know some few doubts in this

1. How the owner sends an automatic notification to the user?
2. How the sender and receiver gets request ( like fb or flipkart order request)?
3. And how the owner accepts and rejects the request?

Comment: What have you searched ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's [FirebaseCloudMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for this purpose.

Basically you have to set up a server between your users and firebaseCloudMessaging, that will manage communication among them and finally messages would be send to devices using FCM via push.